# Comparação de datas JAVA

Tags: java, android, data

Bom pessoal tenho um `array` de strings com datas, oriundo de uma consulta com banco de dados do Firebase. Quero organizá-lo de forma crescente de datas.

Ex: 05/09/2016 - 06/09/2016 - 11/11/2016

As datas são inseridas no meu array pelo método `populateViewHolder`:

```
protected void populateViewHolder(RoomViewHolder viewHolder, EscapeRoom model, int position)
        {
            String [] datasBancoDeDados = new String[] {model.getData()} ;
        }
```

A cada execução do método ele adiciona uma data ao meu array.

Meu objetivo é quando organizar este array com datas, passar para uma `Activity` os valores oriundos dos nós correspondentes estas datas.

Por exemplo a data *05/09/2016* seria antes da data *06/09/2016* e assim passaria os valores do banco de dados para montar uma `RecyclerView` corretamente.

Não sei se expliquei muito bem, vou deixar os prints do app, o que eu tenho por enquanto para melhorar a visualização.

[image: prints do app]

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas você parece ter um array de `String`s contendo datas e quer ordenar esse array.

Se eu tiver entendido corretamente a sua pergunta, que tal fazer assim?

```
public static String[] ordenarDatas(String[] entrada) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    Date[] dates = new Date[entrada.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < entrada.length; i++) {
        try {
            dates[i] = sdf.parse(entrada[i]);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(entrada[i], e);
        }
    }
    Arrays.sort(dates);
    String[] resultado = new String[entrada.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < entrada.length; i++) {
        resultado[i] = sdf.format(dates[i]);
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Os `imports` necessários são esses:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

E então você poderia utilizar assim:

```
protected void populateViewHolder(RoomViewHolder viewHolder, EscapeRoom model, int position) {
    String[] datasBancoDeDados = ordenarDatas(new String[] {model.getData()});
}
```

[Veja aqui um exemplo funcionando no ideone](http://ideone.com/irlwJo).

O exemplo dado cria um novo array de `String` e o retorna, sem alterar o array original. No entanto, se o que você queria era alterar o array original, e não criar um novo array, então basta trocar isso:

```
    Arrays.sort(dates);
    String[] resultado = new String[entrada.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < entrada.length; i++) {
        resultado[i] = sdf.format(dates[i]);
    }
    return resultado;
```

Por isso:

```
    Arrays.sort(dates);
    for (int i = 0; i < entrada.length; i++) {
        entrada[i] = sdf.format(dates[i]);
    }
    return entrada;
```

E ele irá sobreescrever o array dado e retornar o mesmo array recebido no parâmetro. [Veja aqui isso funcionando no ideone](http://ideone.com/jehHHP).

Comment: Exatamente isso, então este código pega o meu array e o deixa organizado,  correto?  Para assim eu pegar as  posições correspondentes as datas corretas?

Comment: @LucasSoares Ele deixará as datas do array em ordem crescente. Se isso serve para você ou não, aí é você que tem que dizer.

Comment: Obrigado farei aqui,  extamente o que eu quero organizar as datas dentro do array obrigado